# Which number of "Reallocated Sectors Count" should I trust in Crystal Disk Info?

Tags: hard-drive, crystaldiskinfo

Using Crystal Disk Info checking the hard drives "Reallocated Sectors Count", which number is the correct one and why do they differ?

Why is the tooltip number different from the one in the list?

I assume the number in the list, but it boggles my that the tooltip is different.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The Load/Unload cycle count is also surprisingly high for a 1 year old drive: about 132000, which is actually huge. I have a 3 years old 4TB WD drive in the small NAS, and it show only 1800 cycles... Typical lifetime of a drive is about 200000/300000 cycles. What is your usage of this drive ?

Comment: OK, from the reference I can see that this is a 2,5" USB drive, correct ? Moreover this is a SMR drive, that is "Shingle Magnetic Recording". This is not a drive made for heavy workloads... I don't say this is the reason why he is failing, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using Crystal Disk Info checking the hard drives' "Reallocated Sectors Count", which number is the correct one, and why do they differ?

The value is stored in hexadecimal, and the notification is displaying the value in decimal.

> Why is the tooltip number different from the one in the list?

They are, in reality, the same number.

Current, Threshold and Worst are all integer values.  As the drive has additional failed sectors, resulting in sectors being reallocated, the Threshold will decrease.  Once it hits 140 the software you are using will considered the drive to be failing.

Comment: Thank you, you were very fast there! So fast I need to wait until I can accept your answer. I figured it out while testing converting the numbers as I saw some values contained letters A-F.

Comment: A side question you might know the answer to, isn't the number quite alarming considering the disk is only slightly more than a year old?

Comment: Indeed this is not normal for a one year old drive. You should contact WD or the vendor and ask for a replacement...

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about contacting WD (see my other comment above)... It also depends all long is the warranty. From now you should closely monitor the SMART status and see if the Reallocated Sector Count is stable or rapidly increasing.

Answer (score -1):

The raw value is `1410` which in hex is equals to `5136` in decimals. What the `194` means I haven't figured out yet though.

| hex | decimal |
| --- | --- |
| 1410 | 5136 |
| <strike>194</strike> | <strike>404</strike> |
| <strike>140</strike> | <strike>320</strike> |

So, the `ID:05` `Raw values` that contains the value in hexadecimal and the value in the tooltip in decimal.

EDIT: the rows strike through are rubbish as they are not in hex in the listing but integers as the comment below says.

Comment: "194" is a normalised value in decimal. In SMART reports, "Current", "Worst", and "Threshold" are all normalised values that range either in 0-100 or in 0-256. 100 (or 256) means a perfect health for the attribute, and if it goes below the threshold value it's time to worry about the drive.